when importing package dill, I encounter FileNotFoundError due to the attempt of opening os.devnull file and couldn't resolve it
Error I encountered first:
I install huggingface package: datasets, when I tried to import datasets, that's when I first encounter the FileNotFoundError from package dill, its something like this:
>>> import datasets
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Administrator\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\datasets\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from .arrow_dataset import Dataset
......(I omitted some intermidia package importing here)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 156, in get_file_type
f = open(os.devnull, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nul'

I need to address that I was able to import torch normally at this time.
The function: get_file_type of _dill.py is like this:
def get_file_type(*args, **kwargs):
open = kwargs.pop("open", __builtin__.open)
f = open(os.devnull, *args, **kwargs)
t = type(f)
f.close()
return t

what I tried:
1.I searched up an answer suggesting change the related line of _dill.py:  f = open(os.devnull, *args, **kwargs) to just f = open('null', *args, **kwargs). It worked, when I tried import datasets in jupyter notebook, as I also found a file named null in the notebook directory. (but I didn't know for sure if it's created by _dill.py itself, or it's created by other packages when I imported them.)
2.then I tried to import datasets in a .py file let's say its called load_dataset.py in pycharm, the same FileNotFoundError happened, only this time suggesting no null file, something like this:
f = open('null', *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'null'

3.I add a new line of code in dill.py getfile_type function to print out what directory its in when the function is being called, it's been called for 6 times under the pycharm project directory. I checked there's no null file under the pycharm project directory, so I manually created one. after that I was also able to import datasets and torch in load_dataset.py, with the line in _dill.py altered as mentioned in step 1.
the problem now:
as mentioned earlier I now am albe to import both datasets and torch in the load_dataset.py file, but when I run another .py file called train_xxnetwork.py , which is under the same directory as load_dataset.py , the same FileNotFoundError happened AGAIN. I think torch is trying to find the null file under other direcotry and there's no null file under what ever direcotry that might be.
at this point I really want to know if I should add more code to get_file_type of _dill.py to manually make null file at relative path, or is it just wrong to change _dill.py in the first place and I should solve it other way around.
information I know:

I'm running on windows 11, there used to be a problem with this machine, under C:\Windows\System32\drivers there's no null.sys file, I added one myself last year

python version: 3.11. I install all mentioned packages with anaconda, their versions are like this


what I don't know:

I don't really know what _dill.py function get_file_type is doing, does it matter if I just give a file type to it instead?

I don't understand the usage of os.devnull and null driver


I'm really confused please help
